# Left join com uma tabela não retorna valor null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Eu tenho este `select`:

```
var pesquisa = (from p in db.Produtos
                            join pe in db.ProdutosEmpresas on p.Id equals pe.ProdutoID into peph
                            from pe_ph in peph.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select new
                            {
                                p.Codigo,
                                p.nome,

                            }).OrderBy(p => p.Codigo).ToList();
```

Se eu faço assim, ele me retorna os registros corretamente, só que eu preciso trazer o campo `EmpresaID` da tabela `ProdutosEmpresas` quando eu coloco pra trazer ele retorna erro, pois ele pode retornar `null`.

No `SQL` ficaria desta forma:

```
select Produtos.Codigo, Produtos.nome, ProdutosEmpresas.EmpresaID from Produtos
left join ProdutosEmpresas on Produtos.id = ProdutosEmpresas.ProdutoID
```

Ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> Nullable object must have a value.

Eu tenho que jogar ele numa list, então preciso do valor `EmpresaID`

```
List<Produto> prod = new List<Produto>();

            foreach (var item in pesquisa)
            {
                Produto produto = new Produto();

                produto.Codigo = item.Codigo;
                produto.nome = item.nome;
                produto.EmpresaID = item.EmpresaID;

                prod.Add(produto);
            }
```

Classe `Produto`

```
 [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }   
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
```

Classe `ProdutosEmpresas`

```
 [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Empresa EmpresaProduto { get; set; }
    public int EmpresaID { get; set; }
    public Produto ProdutoEmpresa { get; set; }
    public int ProdutoID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Olá @marianac_costa. Como é que colocou a propriedade `EmpresaID` no LINQ? Dá erro porquê?

Comment: @JoãoMartins atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: Mariana, por favor colocar a classe Produto na pergunta para ver o tipo de dado que você está declarando.

Comment: @AngeloSimonato pronto, adicionei as duas classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mariana, vou colocar como resposta já pois acho que seja este o caso.

A Classe que você está utilizando está exigindo valores, ou seja, são campos NÃO NULOS.

Quando você está trazendo um campo nulo no select por ser um left join não há a possibilidade de a variável receber um valor nulo por este motivo.

Exemplo:

```
[Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Empresa EmpresaProduto { get; set; }
    public int? EmpresaID { get; set; }
    public Produto ProdutoEmpresa { get; set; }
    public int ProdutoID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu muito bem o que eu gostaria, ele realmente tem que poder vim `null` por isso o `left join`

Comment: Eu entendi, mas vocÊ está atribuindo no código um valor null em uma variável que não aceita null. Inteiro não pode receber null, apenas se for um nullable int ( o que não é o caso da declaração da sua classe)

Comment: Ah sim, agora entendi ,achei que poderia fazer igual um `left join` no `sql` rs  deu certo aqui, obrigado, agora entendi.

Comment: De nada, C# por ser uma linguagem fortemente tipada obriga a ficar atento a esse tipo de questão.